# Kubectl top delivers different results between node and pods

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I noticed that the amount of consumed resources claimed by the `top pods -A` command does not match the one shown by the `top node` one (intended as the sum of pods on a specific node).

In the specific, for a single node I see a difference of about 1Gi in memory consumption, which to me it is quite a lot.
I also tried to query directly the results from the metrics API, which confirms the difference.

Does anyone know why and how could it be possible? Does the `top node` command account also for not running resources? If so, why?

My cluster is running on an Azure AKS managed instance, and I see the same problem both on Linux and Windows nodes.

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl top node`: It displays resource (CPU/Memory/Storage) usage of nodes.

Basically, reserve a portion of the CPU and memory resources for use by the underlying node components such as kubelet, kube-proxy, and the container engine. And it reserves that portion in the first time when you configured the node, then that node divides those memory to the pods or k8s resources according to need.

You can see this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#node-allocatable) for more info.

Comment: in the case I would have been satisfied, if the difference I see could be reconnected to "Total_Mem - Allocatable_Mem", or if the top node command would return the non allocatable part of the resource, both not being the case. In general I see that the top node command scales with the number of pods, and correctly depicts a degraded state if resources are around 100% of the allocatable ones